# Zend routes & SEO

Tags: php, zend-framework, seo

I was wondering how i would go about implementing my site's URLs like `http://mysite.com/ArticleTitleHere` using zend framework.

The way i see it is to implement a regex route, but this way zf will not be able to tell say an article URL from a regular `module/controller/action` or `controller/action` routes. How would i go about implementing such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use placeholders for that in your route:

```
routes.test.route = "/:article"
routes.test.defaults.module = default
routes.test.defaults.controller = test
routes.test.defaults.action = test
routes.test.defaults.article = ""
```

You can retrieve the `article` parameter in your controller using `$this->_getParam("article")`. The rest (matching the database entry by the article's name) is your part.

But you should add something like an url-prefix and/or article id, otherwise other routes may not be found. So use something like this is much better:

```
routes.test.route = "/article/:id/:title"

routes.test.defaults.module = default
routes.test.defaults.controller = test
routes.test.defaults.action = test
routes.test.defaults.article = ""
routes.test.defaults.id = ""
```

You can use the url-Viewhelper this way to create a link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array("id" => $article->id, "title" => $article->title), "test"); ?>"><?php echo $this->escape($article->title); ?></a>
```

And in your controller for a redirect:

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(array("id" => $article->id, "title" => $article->title), "test");
```

Keep in mind escaping or filtering the `$article->title` for invalid characters (or non-ascii-characters).

Comment: Thanks, but from an SEO point of view, 1 level depth is better than 3. So using a prefix for the URL is not gonna solve it.
Lets assume this scenario: all requests are redirected to the article controller, if no article with the specified uri found, redirect request to the router again to re-route the request... is this even possible?

Comment: Put this route as the first entry in your routes.ini (or application.ini, if you're using it as an resource), so the ZF dispatcher will still find the other routes. In the best case, you'll match all your articles now (if not, send a 404 http code). If you still wanna call the dispatcher again (for another route), try `$this->_request->setDispatched(false)` or add another action to the stack: `$this->_helper->actionStack("action", "controller", "module");`

Comment: Thanks... will try this out and accept the answer once confirmed

Comment: If not, please give some feedback too. Thx.